# FixAllTheTags! An app to replace tags

Tags: app

I have to believe this already exists but my search foo sucks so I threw together a small app/script to retag questions for helping me fix some bad tags.

For example you can search for tags with [foo](/questions/tagged/foo) and [bar](/questions/tagged/bar) then say remove [bar](/questions/tagged/bar) and add [moo](/questions/tagged/moo). I have not automated it yet (not sure I will). It just gives the top 30 questions and has a button to manually apply the change one question at a time.

It seems to be working

### How to use

- Go to https://greggman.github.io/fixallthetags/
- Login to Stack Overflow
- Type 2 or more tags: eg. `html canvas`
- Enter tags to remove: eg `canvas` (a meaningless tag)
- Enter tags to add: eg `html5-canvas` (the correct tag)

The questions should show old tags on the left, new tags on the right. If you're feeling lucky/dangerous click `fix` for a question and it should update the tags. Ctrl/Cmd click the link to the question to open it up in Stack Overflow in a new tab and just below the question you should see your user icon and an `edited` link. Click that link to see a diff. It should only show that you changed the tags. If you see anything else please [submit a pull request](https://github.com/greggman/fixallthetags) or [file an issue](https://github.com/greggman/fixallthetags/issues).

Note that one issue it does not grab the latest version of the question before submitting. It's using the version of the question as it was when the search was made. I'll fix that in the near future.

Comment: The behaviour of this bot (or what seems to be a failed trial run) is [under discussion](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/354515/4751173). I apologize for any assumptions I've made, but (IMHO) I've been pretty neutral in my wordings.

Comment: @Glorfindel, sorry for the issue. I changed a question, checked it, saw it was good, changed about 40 more, only then I noticed it was messing up the questions. I revered the 40 or so I'd messed up. Then I fixed the script. I'm still planning to run it later to clean up several tags. `canvas` -> `html5-canvas` when appropriate. [`glsl` -> `glsles` or `glsles3` when appropriate](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/351347/should-we-split-the-glsl-tag-by-version-since-they-are-not-cross-compatible) and maybe a few others that affect me. If you think I shouldn't do this speak up.

Comment: Note I have zero interest in points. I'm just trying to make the site more useful. IMO experts on certain topics should be able to subscribe to tags and not be spammed with question not related to their expertise. That's currently impossible for the canvas tag which is all over the place.

Comment: I do not question your intentions, but there have been [some problems in the past regarding html(5)/canvas/html-canvas tags](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326743/4751173). That's not my area of expertise, but you should perform these kind of large-scale operations only if you have community consensus (either on Meta SO, or a chatroom dedicated to HTML development), never on your own. It's the same procedure as for [burninate requests](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/burninate-request/info).

Comment: There's also benefits to what @Glorfindel has pointed you to. 1) the community will be aware of it, 2) you'll get feedback for whether it needs to be done or not and how it should be approached if required, 3) it can be better coordinated (eg: edit the outliers and then a moderator can bulk rename the remainder avoiding any post bumping and create a synonym to avoid the tag surfacing again etc...)