# Using the API for one-off batch jobs

Tags: support, meta, api-key, stackapps

I'm considering using the API for a retag job not supported by existing tooling as per [this meta post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/356057/648265) (of course, [I'll make sure the community supports the effort before going forward](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/356057/duplicates-dichotomy-excel-vba-vs-excel-vba/356081?noredirect=1#comment510635_356080)).

I'm planning to use [Py-StackExchange](https://stackapps.com/questions/198/py-stackexchange-an-api-wrapper-for-python) (didn't yet looked into details, so may have to consider something else if it doesn't support retagging; also considered [FixAllTheTags](https://stackapps.com/questions/7533/fixallthetags-an-app-to-replace-tags) but it [doesn't allow to set an edit summary](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/46035863/revisions))

The problem is: since I'll need write access, I'm going to [have to register a Stack App to get an API key](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/write). For which, I'll need to provide an app's name, functionality, where it's hosted, its official site, etc.

But, none of that is applicable to my use case. It won't be a web app, nor am I going to let arbitrary users use it, or make an official site and arrange its hosting, all just for the sake of a few hours' work. Nor is there a name or a predefined set of functionality - it's going to just be various odd jobs from time to time as the need arises.

How shall I go about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can just create an [app](/questions/tagged/app) and mark it as a [placeholder](/questions/tagged/placeholder). Those are

> for apps that don't quite work yet, but need a registered Stack Apps post for testing.

Incomplete posts are allowed for placeholder apps, so you don't need to fill in all the details. While this might be bending the rules a bit, as long as it doesn't cause [an avalanche of placeholder apps](https://stackapps.com/q/7490/34061), it's probably fine.

Comment: Since this "app" is never going to go out of the "placeholder" stage, I'm probably required to delete the post once I am done with this particular job, am I not? Or that is clearly going to be an abuse of the tag. And an exact scenario for "avalanche of placeholder apps" since every user potentially has the same needs (with Data.SE, one can read but not write, so there's little need to use API for one-off tasks if you aren't going to write).

Comment: @ivan_pozdeev we've added that requirement after lots of people came here following a certain tutorial. I think most of those people weren't really interested in Stack Exchange; they just wanted to experiment with an Android app. That warning wasn't meant for 'serious' developers using the Stack Exchange API.